# Clear memory of parent class instance created by calling super/extends

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I am facing some memory allocation problem where I have a class Car extending another class CarParent and then creating the instance of Car class somewhere else in the application. But on setting null to car instance is not deleting the instance of parent created because of super keyword.

Class car:

```
export class Car extends CarParent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public go(msg: string): string {
        console.log(msg);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Class CarParent

```
class CarParent {
    constructor() {
    }

    getParts() {
        console.log("you will get parts")
    }
}
```

Inside application:

```
import { Car } from './car';

class Company {
    config;
    car;
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.car = new Car();
    }

    delete() {
        this.car = null;
        this.config = null;
    }
}

function Config(config) {
    const company: Company = new Company(config);
    return company;
}

export default Config;
```

On Index.html

```
<script>
                var config = { place: "france" };
                var box = new Renderer();
                box.delete();
                box = null;
</script>
```

Tried to debug from heap allocation:

First both Car and CarParent instance created(Screenshot):
[image]

After writing box.delete() and box = null and taking snapshot again i can see car instance is deleted:
[image]

But CarParent instance does not delete:
[image]

I am confused. Why this is happening? Is it correct, whatever happening or how can i delete memory occupied by CarParent.

Please help!

Comment: "*writing box.delete() and box = null*" - btw, the latter is enough. If the `Renderer` (`Company`?) instance is garbage-collected, so will the `.car` and `.config` references.

Comment: @Bergi - looks like OP has two different operations. `box.delete()` is a method on the `box` object that deletes `config` and `car` object references on that object, then `= null` is used to remove `box`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, and I'm saying that `box = null` is enough, making the box object, the config and the car object eligible to be garbage collected.

Comment: @Bergi - of-course I realize that, but I'm suggesting the OP has a purpose for both and perhaps run into this problem will trying each/both to demonstrate that these objects are not being GC'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the instance of parent created because of super keyword

No, `super()` does not create a separate instance.

> I am confused. Why this is happening?

The `CarParent` "instance" you are seeing in the heap snapshot is `Car.prototype` - it's an object inheriting from `CarParent.prototype`. You can see how it holds the `.go` method and `Car` as its `.constructor`.

You do not want to delete it.

Comment: What is meant by "You do not want to delete it.". Could you please elaborate? Will it help when multiple instance of Company get's created?

Comment: It's part of the `class Car`, it's not a particular instance. You do not want to clear its memory.

Comment: "*Will it help when multiple instance of Company get's created?*" - try it. You'll not see it get duplicated. But really, I recommend not to use heap snapshots while still learning the language.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @bergi, But if it is part of class Car, why i am not seeing Car along with CarParent after running box.delete() or box = null ?

Comment: It's part of the *class*, not of the `box.car` instance.